# How to extract a type from a typed Array

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am importing a file that only exports a typed array of the interface I am looking for ie.

imported `file.ts`

```
interface IOrg {
    name: string
    address: string
    phone: string
    rank: number
}

export type OrgArray = IOrg[]
```

I really want to use just the type `IOrg` is there anyway to extract it from `OrgArray: IOrg[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type query :

```
import { OrgArray} from '. /file'
type IOrg = OrgArray [number]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make a index.d.ts file
2. add the interface in a global daclaration /

   ```js
       interface IOrg {
           name: string
           address: string
           phone: string
           rank: number
       }
   ```

   if the `index.d.ts` isn't in the same folder as the file needing it just import the folder where the file is in